# How to create a regular expression to parse TLS versions on an Apache access log?

Tags: regex

I have log messages that have a lot of details in them (typical http access log). An example is like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2021:12:25:08 +1200] "POST /something HTTP/1.1" 200 134 Time: 727 "https://www.example.com/something" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "JSESSIONID=..." "-" "TLSv1.3" "SomeHeader=123"
```

How can I extract the list of values for TLS (e.g. TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, etc) using a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

it is easy for the showing situations,the regex is `TLSv[\d\.]+`.
But I do not think it apply to all situations.

And it seems a nginx log,but not a typical nginx,it's customized.there is a lot bash script to parse nginx log,you can get inspired by the [script](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/log-parsing/),they typically using `awk`